# Converting LOAD DATA UNFILE MySQL UPDATE to php

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a MySQL update statement which updates a table from a csv file. This command works perfectly when run from phpMyAdmin, but when trying to run it from php it fails. It says there is an error in my syntax.

This is my php code snippet

```
$file = "/root/location/to/file.csv";
$db = IEM::getDatabase();
$recover = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable LIKE email_list_subscribers; LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE temptable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (emailaddress, subscriberid, confirmed); UPDATE email_list_subscribers INNER JOIN temptable on temptable.subscriberid = email_list_subscribers.subscriberid SET email_list_subscribers.confirmed = temptable.confirmed; DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temptable;";
$result = $db->Query($recover);
```

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

the error message gets truncated to:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspond...
```

Comment: What is the error msg exactly... that might suggest your problem

Comment: As a first step, I would verify that the `Query` function of the `$db` object supports executing multiple queries. (A lot of interface libraries disallow that.) Is the syntax error being reported by the MySQL server, or is it a PHP syntax error, or something else. The error message usually gives an indication of where the problem is.

Comment: added error message that can be seen

Comment: It looks like a mysql server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @spencer7593 suggestion. The `Query` function did not support multiple queries. Hence my answer was as follows:

```
$file = "/root/location/to/file.csv";
$db = IEM::getDatabase();
$recover = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable LIKE email_list_subscribers;";
$result = $db->Query($recover); 
$recover ="LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE temptable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (emailaddress, subscriberid, confirmed);";
$result = $db->Query($recover); 
$recover = "UPDATE email_list_subscribers INNER JOIN temptable on temptable.subscriberid = email_list_subscribers.subscriberid SET email_list_subscribers.confirmed = temptable.confirmed;";
$result = $db->Query($recover);
$recover = "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temptable;";
$result = $db->Query($recover);
```